# angular-datatables: with server-side ajax data twice return (Angular 1.x + TypeScript)

Tags: ajax, datatable, promise, datasource, angular-datatables

I'm working with angular-datatables in a project: **Angular 1.x + typescript.**

Render mode with: **server-side ajax.**

angular-datatables latest version!.

The problem that I have the argument: data, returns 2 times (making two requests and affects the draw.

Only it occurs when dtOptions is not within a promise or $resource. If I draw function independently, it works right. However, within any $resource or resource that invoke the $watchcollection, no.

**Code:**

```
$self.dtOptions = $self.DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption("ajax", {
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "*/*",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "Authorization": catalogOptions.headers
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: catalogOptions.url,
                    data: function (data, settings) {
                        console.log("I'm data: I passed here");
                        data = angular.toJson(dataCriteria);
                        return data;
                    },
                    dataSrc: (result) => {
                        if (!$self.ngUtil.isUndefinedOrNull(result) && result.products instanceof Array) {
                            $self.products = new Array<common.models.ICartProduct>();
                            (result.products as Array<common.models.ICatalogProductSummary>).forEach((value: common.models.ICatalogProductSummary, index: number, array: Array<common.models.ICatalogProductSummary>) => {
                                $self.products.push(new common.models.CartProduct(0, value));
                            });
                            // [stats] API
                            result.recordsTotal = result.totalCount;
                            result.recordsFiltered = result.totalCount;
                            return $self.products;
                        }
                        return new Array<common.models.ICartProduct>();
                    }
```

**Result:**

> Log

[image: Log]

> Requests

[image: Requests]

> Call stack

[image: Call stack]

Thanks for your help!.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I also have same issue, did you get any solution